# mysql_fetch_array from two different rows

Tags: php, mysql

I am having difficulty to explain this problem, but I will try anyway.

I have two different database rows

```
  SOMETHING
*---------------------------------------------------------*
|    id    |    category_id    |    body                  |
*---------------------------------------------------------*

  CATEGORY
*---------------------------------------------------------*
|    id    |    title    |    description                 |
*---------------------------------------------------------*
```

Now, I want to extract data from both rows at the samt time, how do i do this?

I need to extract values from SOMETHING and display the info from CATEGORY from the category_id in SOMETHING - how is this done the best way ?

I use to extract values like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from SOMETHING WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   extract($row);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a join

```
SELECT
    S.id,
    S.category_id,
    S.body,
    C.title,
    C.description
FROM SOMETHING AS S
JOIN CATEGORY AS C
ON S.category_id = C.id
WHERE id = '42'
LIMIT 1
```

If there might not be a matching row in the CATEGORY table you could use a LEFT JOIN instead.

Comment: Thanks, can you give me an example on how to print the description from the category then? What if both rows has "description" ?

Comment: @2by: You can give each column a unique alias. `SELECT S.description AS something_description, C.description AS column_description, ...etc...`

Comment: Ah okay, thanks, i will try that. And yes, i need to use LEFT JOIN i can see.

Comment: Can i select all results from SOMETHING? Like S.* ?

Comment: @2by: Yes, but there are good reasons why that is not recommended, and they have been discussed before at great length on this site so I won't repeat it all here.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should join the two tables together:

```
SELECT * FROM SOMETHING, CATEGORY WHERE SOMETHING.category_id=CATEGORY.id AND 
SOMETHING.id='$id' LIMIT 1
```

Make sure you sanitize $id coming into the database!

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM SOMETHING INNER JOIN CATEGORY ON CATEGORY.id = SOMETHING.category_id WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");
```

This is susceptible to SQL injection though.

Comment: @2by - by "susceptible to SQL injection", stealthyninja is warning you against EVER passing ANY user input directly into a SQL query.  GlaciesofPacis is also warning you of the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely want a "join".  Here's another example:

```
select a.id ID, b.title TITLE, b.description DESCRIPTION, a.body TEXT
from something a 
inner join category b on a.id = b.id;
```